# Javascript functions how this is giving output 5,6,7

Tags: javascript

How this program is giving output 5 6 7

Please explain me the code

Output:
5 
6
7
undefined

Code

```js
var a = (function() {
  var x = 5;

  function m() {
    console.log(x++);
  }
  return m;

}());

function b() {
  a();
  a();
  a();
}
b();
```

Comment: Is there something in particular you don't understand? What output would you expect instead?

Comment: Did you expect it to output something else?

Answer (score 2):

`var a` is the result of an Immediately Invoked Expression Function (IIEF)

```
var a = (function() {
    ...
}());
```

in this IIEF we have a local variable, x, initialised with a value 5

```
var x = 5;
```

we also have a function, m that outputs the value of x to the console, and then adds 1 to the value of x: `x++` is shorthand for `x = x + 1`

```
function m() {
    console.log(x++);
}
```

the IIEF returns the function (not the result of the function) - which is how `var a` is now sort of a reference to the function `m` - this means invoking a, by using the notation `a()` is invoking the code defined by `function m`

```
  return m;
```

next, function b is defined as simply invoking function a 3 times

```
function b() {
  a();
  a();
  a();
}
```

next, function b is invoked - `b()`

```
b();
```

this invokes `function a` for a first time

which invokes `function m`

which outputs the value of `x`, which is 5, then increases `x` to be 6

now b invokes `function a` for a second time

which invokes `function m`

which outputs the value of `x`, which is now 6, then increases `x` to be 7

now b invokes `function a` for a third time

which invokes `function m`

which outputs the value of `x`, which is now 7, then increases `x` to be 8

as nothing is returned from `function b`, and you are running this on some sort of console (browser dev tools or node maybe) the console logs the result of the `function b`, which is undefined when there is no `return` value

Answer (score 0):

The concept of an inner function referencing a variable from an outer scope is called **closure**.

The variable is being declared just once when you call the outer function and assign the function it returns to another variable. Each time you invoke the returned function it is working with and modifying a variable which now can only be referenced by the returned function.